# best query for a complex situation

Tags: sql, database

I have a table with following columns,(id,fkid, flag1,flag2,flag3,flag4). The possible value for each flag field is -1 to 3 and null is allowed. What I need is a query to check if count of any flag field with value 2 is greater than 3 for a given foreign key fkid. The way I am doing is write a query for each field. It works but very not smart to me. Anyone has better idea? Thanks.

Comment: it looks like your database is not normalized properly, also its hard to help with so little information, can you show us the table create and the queries you're working with ?

Comment: Isn't all "[value] 2 [is] greater than 3" false? (Showing current attempts would make the question more clear. Posting the execution times, query plan, and schema are crucial to "performance" questions.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with one query:

```
select fkid
from t
group by fkid
having sum(case when flag1 = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 3 or
       sum(case when flag2 = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 3 or
       sum(case when flag3 = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 3 or
       sum(case when flag4 = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 3
```

I do agree strongly with the comments, though, that sample data, sample results, and a clear table structure would greatly improve the question.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. This is exactly what I looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Query below will also answer your question, sql fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/adda9/2

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT fkid 
FROM
  tblTest pvt
UNPIVOT
  (
    FlagValue FOR Flag IN
       (flag1,flag2,flag3,flag4)
  ) as Unpvt
WHERE
  FlagValue = 2
GROUP BY
  FKID, FLAG
HAVING COUNT(*)>3
```

Comment: Thanks. This is more cleaner approach for checking out a lot of columns.